# PHPMailer Sending emails to two users with different body

Tags: php, phpmailer

Good day. I need to send two different messages to two different people (user and admin). Tell me how to do this?

My mail php

```
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];                         

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'pmewilberries@mail.ru';
$mail->Password = '123456789456';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           
$mail->Port = 465; 

$mail->setFrom('pmewilberries@mail.ru'); 
$mail->addAddress($email);     


$mail->Subject = 'Заявка на участие в интенсиве Wildberries';


// $mail->Body($body);
// $mail->isHTML(true);
$body = 'Hello'
$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->send()
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send one message, change the properties that are different, then send the second one:

```php
$mail->addAddress($email);
$body = 'Hello';
$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->send();
$mail->clearAddresses();
$mail->addAddress($email2);
$body = 'Hello2';
$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->send();
```

It will be slightly quicker if you set keepalive, which will make it re-use the existing connection for the second message:

```
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
```

Comment: And where it would be better to indicate $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; At the beginning of all code or at the end?

Comment: Anywhere before the first call to `send()`, but it would make most sense to put it with the rest of the setup near the top.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$mail->addAddress($email);
$body = 'Hello';
$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->send();
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();

$mail->addAddress($email2);
$body = 'Hello2';
$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->send();
```

Look at the code for clearAllRecipients;